# Bluetooth 4.0 A2DP and BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, a2dp

I am trying to communicate to a printer via a mobile and use BLE for communication. It works good for some mobiles (ofcourse that have BLE support)

The customer has purchased few mobiles that mention Bluetooth 4.0, A2DP

http://www.gsmarena.com/gionee_pioneer_p2-6091.php

I am not sure if this one will support BLE. Since it is 4.0. It should... isnt it??

Or is there a turn around for how I can implement BLE on this mobile

There are some issues with printing on classic (Customer demand) and hence is not preferred.